# Почему не подключаются модули в gulpfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Решил разбить свой gulpfile на таски в отдельные файлы. Экспортирую их в gulpfile и прохожу циклом по ним, но почему-то не подключаются. В чем может быть причина?

```
// gulpfile.js

const { dest, src, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const pathTasks = require('./gulp/path/tasks.js');

pathTasks.forEach(function (taskPath) {
    require(taskPath)();
});
module.exports.start = series(scripts); // запускаю таск

// tasks.js

module.exports = [
    './gulp/tasks/pug2html',
    './gulp/tasks/styles',
    './gulp/tasks/scripts'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Установите [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir)
и далее requireDir("./tasks/")